# NextJS: How do I create API routes as a package or module to share across multiple projects

Tags: next.js

I want to create a few API routes in a package and build it and want to include it as part of multiple NextJS projects as a dependency so all of them can use it. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to import the API route handler from your module, and export it inside the API route file:

```js
// Your module file -- customHandlers.js
export function customHandlerOne(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'This is custom handler 1' })
}

export function customHandlerTwo(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'This is custom handler 2' })
}
```

```js
// Your API route -- api/routeOne.js
import {customHandlerOne} from 'customHandlers';

export default customHandlerOne;
```

```js
// Your other API route -- api/routeTwo.js
import {customHandlerTwo} from 'customHandlers';

export default customHandlerTwo;
```